# Breach or very strange coincidence?

Tags: support, security

It has been too long since I've updated my password on Stack Overflow, so I decided to do so a couple of days ago. I accidentally set it as the same password that I used on an old (forgotten, unused and totally empty) GitHub account connected to my email address.

The very next day I received an email from GitHub saying that there was deprecated API access to this unused GitHub account:

> On September 22nd, 2020 at 11:36 (UTC) you used a password to access an endpoint through the GitHub API using python-requests/2.18.4: https://api.github.com/user

I was most definitely asleep at this time.

Further, I have not logged into this GitHub account in about 2-3 years. I only remembered it because of this email from GitHub I received after changing my password on Stack Overflow to the same GitHub password.

No other accounts I have use this password.

I've never accessed GitHub using Python; I am a piss-poor Python programmer.

I deleted the GitHub account shortly afterwards and considered changing my password on Stack Overflow again, but I realized that it would be rather dense seeing how I ended up here.

Any insight on this from support?

Comment: Any indications of malware on your OS or browser? That would be my first suspicion

Comment: @CertainPerformance Nothing I could see off the bat, AV seems to be behaving normally but I will poke around some more.

Comment: Maybe I can ask github where the request originated from

Comment: Stack Exchange is a C# shop, so a *Python* request is less likely to be to have come from there. Are you sure you never used the same password and email account anywhere else, like adobe.com, any time in the past, that has had their database leaked? Because script kiddies are perusing password leak databases all the time to see if those leaked passwords can be used in other places.

Comment: It is a pity that you deleted the account however as you could have seen the IP address of the account that logged in with Python *in the Github.com security log*. That would have told us much more.

Comment: Regardless of your question, I have two important recommendations: 1) **Do change your password** on SO (especially if you use the same email address for the GitHub account) because that particular password appears to have been leaked. 2) **Use a password manager** so you don't have to remember (and reuse) passwords.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks and that makes sense re python, I'm awaiting a response from github support, hopefully they will help me out by telling me the originating IP despite the account deletion. Going to change the PW now and look into password manager.

Comment: @egerardus I would also suggest looking at this website: https://howsecureismypassword.net/. Make sure your password wouldn't be cracked in like 2 seconds. If you use a password manager, you can have very complicated passwords as well.

Comment: @egerardus you can check if that email address was part of a password database leak at https://haveibeenpwned.com/ or https://monitor.firefox.com/

Comment: Thanks again @MartijnPieters, I checked it out and am relieved to report: "no pwnage found!" on the first and "0 known data breaches" on firefox, really hoping to get an answer from github soon and will update then.